# How to convert a vector into a matrix where values on columns are 1 where the column number is the vector element, else 0?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I'm unsure how to phrase the question, but I think an example will help. Suppose I have a vector y = [3;1;4;1;6]. I want to create the matrix Y =

```
[0     0     1     0     0     0;
 1     0     0     0     0     0;
 0     0     0     1     0     0;
 1     0     0     0     0     0;
 0     0     0     0     0     1]

 ↑     ↑     ↑     ↑     ↑     ↑
 1     2     3     4     5     6
```

where the element on each column is one or zero corresponding to the value in the vector.

I found that I could do it using

```
Y = []; for k = 1:max(y); Y = [Y (y==k)]; end
```

Can I do it without a for loop (and is this method more efficient if y has thousands of elements)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is not efficient because you're growing the size of `Y` in the loop which is [not a good programming practice](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). Here is how your code can be fixed:

```
Ele = numel(y); 
Y= zeros(Ele, max(y));
for k = 1:Ele
    Y (k,y(k))= 1;
end
```

And here is an alternative approach without a loop:

```
Ele = numel(y);          %Finding no. of elements in y
Y= zeros(Ele, max(y));   % Initiailizing the matrix of the required size with all zeros
lin_idx = sub2ind(size(Y), 1:Ele, y.'); % Finding linear indexes
Y(lin_idx)=1             % Storing 1 in those indexes
```

Comment: Thanks, Sardar_Usama. Works great! Is there a reason for using "y.' " instead of just "y' " on the third line. Also, is sub2ind more efficient than using for if there are at most 10 columns?

Comment: @Gnubie Because the size of `I` and `J` in `sub2ind(SIZ,I,J)` should be same. It should be efficient in terms of speed!

Comment: @Sadar_Usama: I can see why you transpose y, but found that y' is identical to y.' (extra dot in your answer). What's the difference?

Comment: @Gnubie ! Simple `'` is not a transpose. It is complex conjugate which is same as transpose if there is not complex element. Read the documentation for reference here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html and here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html

Comment: @Gnubie The idea of using `sub2ind` is actually better than `bsxfun` here, especially if `y` can have large values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = double(bsxfun(@eq, y(:), 1:max(y)));
```

If you are running the code on Matlab version R2016b or later, you can simplify the syntax to

```
result = double(y(:)==(1:max(y)));
```

---

Another approach, possibly more efficient, is to fill in the values directly using [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
result = accumarray([(1:numel(y)).' y(:)], 1);
```

Comment: this solution is slow : n^2 operations, of which n (n-1) are a check leading to nothing, and only n lead to writing a 1.

Comment: @titus You are right. I have added another approach which is probably more efficient

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution:

```
E = eye(max(y));
Y = E(y,:);
```

Comment: This looks quite neat, but not as fast as `sub2ind` approach. Beware! If `max(y) >> numel(y)`, this becomes by far the slowest. But if `max(y) << numel(y)`, this is almost as good as `sub2ind`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
Y = repmat(1:max(y), size(y)) == repmat(y, 1, max(y))
```